# Writing generic function for auto mapping

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I have more than 8 pages in a modules for a .NET MVC3 based project. I have a single controller to handle all the pages. When I get the value from the view, I have to convert to the local model for doing the logic in the business layer. To convert the model from `ViewModel`, I'm using Auto Mapper. Is there any possibility for making the Auto Mapper as a generic function?

Here is the code which I'm using:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<WorkLoadRatioViewModel, WorkLoadRatio>();
WorkLoadRatio _workloaddata = Mapper.Map<WorkLoadRatioViewModel, WorkLoadRatio>(_vmodel);
Mapper.CreateMap<LeadTimeDayDetailsViewModel, LeadTimeDayDetails>();
LeadTimeDayDetails _leadtimedata = Mapper.Map<LeadTimeDayDetailsViewModel,LeadTimeDayDetails>(_vmodel);
```

Is there a way to bring all the code just to call a generic function? For example,

```
public static TModel ToModel<TModel>(TModel model,TViewModel viewmodel) 
where TModel : class
{
    //mapper function to return the TModel OBject.
}
```

Comment: yes, there probably is. You should expand your question, getting the spelling of Generic right for instance, show some example of your efforts so far and mark some answers to previous questions as accepted.

Comment: I helped you out with the English, the rest is down to you.

Comment: Hey Jordell , Thanks again. I have Edited the post. If it aint clear. I might be Edit till its clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do:

```
public TDest Map<TSource, TDest>(TSource viewModel)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDest>();
    TDest result = Mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>(viewModel);

    return result;
}

public ActionResult MyAction(WorkLoadRationViewModel viewModel)
{
    WorkLoadRatio model = Map<WorkLoadRationViewModel, WorkLoadRatio>(viewModel);
}
```